# Context menu preview not with rounded corners in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

When using a `plain` styled `List` in SwiftUI with more than one `Text` view inside a `VStack` as show below, the preview of the view when showing its context menu doesn't have corner radius. If you remove one of the `Text` views it will have corner radius. Also the rows that you need to scroll down to will also show corner radius most of the time. I've tried using the `contentShape` modifier with `RoundedRectangle` but doesn't fix it. How can I get it to show with corner radius all the time?

```swift
List {
  ForEach(1...20, id: \.self) { _ in
    VStack {
      Text("Hello")
      Text("World")
    }.contextMenu {
      Button {} label: { Text("Hello") }
    }
  }
}.listStyle(.plain)
```

[image: Context menu]

Comment: On what kind device did you try ? tested on Xcode 13.1 and iOS 15.0  simulator and the VStack with 2 elements is correctly rounded

Comment: @Hikosei Thanks. So far I've tried on 12, 13, 13 Pro and 13 Pro Max on Xcode 13 and iOS 15 which all reproduce the issue. Which exact device worked for you?

Comment: Good a reproduce, for information it work nice with iPod Touch 7th generation, the smaller device.

Answer (score 0):

I thinks you should fill a bug to Apple in this case.

After some try I have notice that if you define a frame for your Label , the view is correctly rounded.
[image]

I tryed to fixedSize the text without success :

```
Text("world").fixedSize()
```

The problem seems to come from _UIMorphingPlatterView, more precisely the _UIPlatterClippingView which use _UIPortalView.

If the frame is not fixed the clip is not apply correctly.

The debug view hierarchy give this :

[image]